# C# StreamReader Holding up the process even if I close

Tags: c#, file-io, streamreader

I am currently getting these errors:

```
Error   18  Could not copy "obj\Debug\SoldierApp.exe" to "bin\Debug\SoldierApp.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

Error   19  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\SoldierApp.exe" to "bin\Debug\SoldierApp.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\SoldierApp.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

So I am guessing that my `StreamReader` is not closing appropriately somewhere. Though I know I've closed it. Here is my code.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(File.Exists("soldier.csv"))
        {
            sr = new StreamReader("soldier.csv");
            string stream_line;
            int intCommaIndex1 = 0;
            int intCommaIndex2;
            string strSubStringSect;
            stream_line = sr.ReadLine();
            while(stream_line != EOF) //EOF is a constant
            {
                intCommaIndex1 = stream_line.IndexOf(",", intCommaIndex1);
                intCommaIndex2 = stream_line.IndexOf(",", intCommaIndex1);
                strSubStringSect = stream_line.Substring(intCommaIndex1, intCommaIndex2);
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + " " + strSubStringSect;
                intCommaIndex1 = intCommaIndex2;
                stream_line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close(); //closed here!
        }

    }
```

Fairly new to `C#` File IO and to me it looks as though everything is right? Any suggestions as to why I am getting these errors?

Comment: Well you should use a `using` statement, to start with, instead of calling `Close()` manually. Otherwise, if an exception is thrown, you *won't* be calling `Close`. Also, it looks like it's an instance variable - you'd be much better off making it a local variable, almost certainly...

Comment: Oh, but the file that it can't copy isn't the file that you're reading anyway. I suspect you've still got one instance of the app running, which is why you can't build a newer version which needs to be copied into the same place.

Comment: I have no instances up. That's my problem. I can not use `using` as our professor has not taught that, I know ridiculous really because this is not our best case method in the real world. That is what irks me. I've read the c# msdn or whatever but I need to use `Close` but I'll try shutting my computer down and starting back up. I did accidentally have an infinite loop from the while `EOF` and not repriming the `stream_line` read

Comment: If you can't use `using`, then wrap everything in a `try-catch`, and call `Close` in the `finally` block.

Comment: Why do you have `InitializeComponent();` inside the `if` statement? It should be before.

Comment: "I have no instances up" - well, check in Task Manager. But it's not the StreamReader that's the problem, because that's not the same file...

Comment: The entire thing inside the `if` could be replaced with `richTextBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", File.ReadAllLines("soldier.txt").TakeWhile(line => line != EOF).Select(line => line.Split(',')[1]));`. Perhaps try that and see if the problem goes away? That way you'll know if your code is the issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity can't use what you suggested sorry. But yes the `InitializeComponent();` was moved around I was trying to see if that was my problem I forgot to move it back -_-

Comment: @EasyBB - Why can't you use what I suggest to see if your code is the actual problem? If mine works and yours doesn't then keep debugging your code. If mine also doesn't work then it's not your code either.

Comment: Got it working now after restarting the computer and basically closing the opened program that @JonSkeet suggested was alive just not showing. It was an error in my while loop constantly putting the same text in the `richTextBox1`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue a quite few times that it says "The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Some.exe' because it is being used by another process."

Normally you should **Clean the Solution and Rebuild it again** and it would fix the issue.

```
Build -> Clean Solution
```

Then

```
Build -> Rebuild Solution
```

If this does not fix the issue. Than You should manually delete the `Soldier.exe` from bin folder and build the Solution again

Comment: Yeah I've cleaned and rebuilt about 10 times now. I may go with the deleting exe next

Comment: Well all it took was restarting my computer, there must have been an app opened but not shown because of the mistake I made in the while loop before realizing it and starting it up. So that must have been my error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to use using. This way the file will be closed (and the reader disposed) even if you end up getting an exception.
Other thing is, ReadLine returns null if it reached the end of the stream. 
But there is a useful property in StreamReader: EndOfStream. Which is true when you reached the end of the stream.

So I would suggest a code like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    if(File.Exists("soldier.csv"))
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("soldier.csv"))
        {
            string stream_line;
            int intCommaIndex1 = 0;
            int intCommaIndex2;
            string strSubStringSect;
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                stream_line = sr.ReadLine();
                intCommaIndex1 = stream_line.IndexOf(",", intCommaIndex1);
                intCommaIndex2 = stream_line.IndexOf(",", intCommaIndex1);
                strSubStringSect = stream_line.Substring(intCommaIndex1, intCommaIndex2);
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + " " + strSubStringSect;
                intCommaIndex1 = intCommaIndex2;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Clearly you did not read the comments above. I'd love to use the proper methodology such as `using` but sadly I cannot, my professor will mark points off me. He's done this to me before for using silly things such as in C++ using EOF. or while loops. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot when debugging on Visual Studio because of the "hosting process". Is vshost.exe on your running processes?

Close Visual Studio, re-open your solution and then try the following:

1. On the Project menu, click Properties.
2. Click the Debug tab.
3. Clear the Enable the Visual Studio hosting process check box.

This might solve your problem if vshost.exe is still holding on to your file.